# TStringGrid: Why OnClick after OnKeyDown

Tags: delphi, onclick, onkeydown, tstringgrid

Why does a Delphi StringGrid sometimes calls the `OnClick` event after an `OnKeyDown`?

Debugging screenshot:

[image]

My OnKeyDown event handler:

```
var
  Top: Integer;
  Bottom: Integer;
  CurrentRow: Integer;
begin
  Top := Grid.TopRow;
  Bottom := Grid.TopRow + Grid.VisibleRowCount - 1;
  if (Key = 38) then CurrentRow := Grid.Row - 1
  else if (Key = 40) then CurrentRow := Grid.Row + 1;
  
  // Disable OnClick because sometimes a 'TStringGrid.Click' is called anyway...
  // (when clicking on form top window bar and navigating)
  Grid.OnClick := nil; 
  
  if (CurrentRow < Top - 1) or (CurrentRow > Bottom + 1) then begin
     if (Key = 38) then Grid.Row := Bottom
     else if (Key = 40) then Grid.Row := Top;
  end;
  Grid.OnClick := GridClick;
end;
```

**Edit:**

It seems the 'OnClick' is not being fired when the last line is selected and pushing 'Down' or when the first line is selected and pushing 'Up'.

Way to reproduce:

Add a TStringGrid to a form and populate with a few lines. Add 'OnClick' and 'OnKeyDown' handler. No specific code needs to be added in these two handler methods. Select a row in the stringgrid on the form and press the up or down arrow on your keyboard.

**Edit 2:**

This isn't the solution, but to prevent the code in 'OnClick' being executed after pressing up, down, pageup or pagedown, I set a variable in 'OnKeyDown' what key was pressed and check for that variable in 'OnClick'.

**Edit 3:**

Updated stack trace and way to reproduce.

Comment: Which version of Delphi? There is nothing in `TCustomGrid.KeyDown` in XE3 that calls `TControl.Click`. And would it be too much to ask for a way to reproduce this?

Comment: Delphi XE3. I added a the way to reproduce this to the description.

Comment: Your reproduction is incomplete. Which keys do you need to press? Describe precise steps to reproduce.

Comment: Why all the edits? You asked why; I told you why. You don't accept; now what question is left?

Comment: 1) Being able to reproduce and verify. 2) Search for a solution (I know, not really part of the question). 3) Accept answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, that hard-coded key codes aren't the case making the least bit transparent, but you witness this *effect* when you use a direction key (up, down, left, etc...) to change the selection.

Why the `OnClick` event handler is called, is because `TCustomGrid.OnKeyDown` calls `TCustomGrid.FocusCell`, which calls `Click`.

Exactly why changing focus to another cell would establish a *click* I do not know, we would have to ask the developers I imagine. Perhaps to simulate the default behaviour when changing focus to another cell by clicking instead of keyboard.

Since you seem to handle direction key presses yourself, maybe you could consider to prevent this from happening at all by ignoring the key any further:

```
  if Key in [VK_PRIOR..VK_DOWN] then
    Key := 0;
```

Comment: Indeed, in my test program I see 'TCustomGrid.FocusCell' in the stack trace before going into 'Click'.

Comment: @user729103 Your screenshot in the question does not show that. A big part of my problem with this question is that your call stack in the question does not match the real call stack.